# Using qsort To Sort Array Of Structs

Tags: c, arrays, file, qsort

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct  
{  int occurrence
   char  charArray[101]; 
}Wordy;


int comparing(const void *a, const void *b) 
{
   //....
}

int main(void)
{  
        int i=0;
    Wordy array[99999];

  //.....



    return 0;

}

*/
```

This program reads words from a file, then the occurrence of the word is calculated. Everything works, but I don't think the qsort function is working correctly in the comparing function. It's suppose to sort `array` in terms of its occurrence. (Finding its occurrence is correct.)

My sample text file:

```
zero one
two zero
three three
```

Output:

```
Before: zero one two three 

After:  one two three
```

(notice that zero is missing after sorting)

Comment: You refer to `array[1].word` and `array[0].word` but `Wordy` has no member named `word`, does this compile?

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
qsort(array, i, sizeof(int), comparing);
```

is wrong, `array`  is not an array of `int`, it's an array of `Wordy`. When you specify the wrong element size to `qsort()`, the results are more or less random since you're going to get pointers into `int`-sized "slices" of the `Wordy` struct array.

Try:

```
qsort(array, i, sizeof array[0], comparing);
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it because your `printf` statements are different? `word` and `charArray` ordered differently.

Before:

**array[0].charArray, array[1].word,** array[2].charArray, array[3].charArray);

After:

**array[0].word, array[1].charArray,** array[2].charArray, array[3].charArray);